# Sysprep without audit mode?

Tags: windows-7, audit, sysprep, cloning

In preparing a (windows 7) machine for cloning, does one need to run it in audit mode before installing/customising? I have a customised machine I would like to sysprep and clone, without having to re-create in audit mode.

And from where does one run sysprep? Is the command included in the windows distro, or do I need to run it from the AIK, or from a PE environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sysprep is located in `C:\windows\System32\sysprep` on Windows 7. No need to pull it off the CD anymore.

When you say customized, do you mean the user account is set up like you want it? I have been cloning Windows 7 using the Out of Box Experience option and the Generalize option. You have to go through the mini-setup again, and set up a new user account. Hope this helps a little bit.